# Typescript: type ConstructorParameters does not accept generic

Tags: typescript, types

Using typescript 3.7, I have an interface with a property that is meant to accept a constructor function:

```
interface IConstruct<T> {
  type: new (...args:ConstructorParameters<T>) => T;
}
```

My thought is that `IConstruct<User>` will have a property `{type: User}`.
But the compiler tells me that `T` cannot be used there. Why is that?

> TS2344: Type T does not satisfy the constraint 'new (...args: any) => any'

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The type of `ConstructorParameters` looks like this:

```
type ConstructorParameters<T extends new (...args: any) => any> =
  T extends new (...args: infer P) => any ? P : never;
```

So type parameter `T` itself has to extend some sort of constructor function defined by the constraint `extends new (...args: any) => any`. Write above example like this and you should be good to go:

```
class User {
    constructor(public name: string) { }
}

// add constructor function type constraint for T
interface IConstruct<T extends new (...args: any) => any> {
    // we can use built-in InstanceType to infer instance type from class type
    type: new (...args: ConstructorParameters<T>) => InstanceType<T>;
}

type UserConstruct = IConstruct<typeof User>

const constr: UserConstruct = {
    type: User
}

constr.type // new (name: string) => User

const userInstance = new constr.type("John") // userInstance: User

console.log(userInstance.name) // John
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=21&pc=39#code/MYGwhgzhAECqEFMBO0DeAoaXrAPYDsIAXJAV2CNyQAoAHUgIxAEthp8wBbBALmmKTN8AcwCUaaAF9009AHo50MABNlOAgPKUUAM1L4KzAtCIBPWgnWESYIUWg6q0ACro7yHWGCWAkgGENEi0AHmdoBAAPIgR8ZRh8BAB3aGoAOnSwJGEIPjB8U3EAXgA+JXzSjGxoBWhEy2A86FJEaAZSZhAiAFohaB9rPO9nc0tKaCEdZHGBg1GRhyRcThxwKBMRzGwzCz4E5LSMrJzoAOsyCioABUyuBGikCFDiotL+4kGEYYsngG4ZdHQ20s8GQp00FGghT6YKCFGCQNwOjgiCQxQBeGsVgEfBBSBh53sUMqWxGOJR-3QGIEqSB1UUexSHG4fAEQjEkNKuPRgSaKLeRA+kPYSSxJBpI2oACIAFK4AAW+El4hqzWQ-I+ZOQ3MIuBACFSIFwwmoqqQ6tmqSZCGVillCqAA)

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  How come when you declared your type `T1` you used `typeof User` instead of just `User` ?  Isn't `User` already a type?

Comment: @BeetleJuice Not quite, there is a difference: `User` is the type of the instance, `typeof User` is the actual class type. [Here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#constructor-functions) is a good example in the docs.

Comment: @BeetleJuice Updated the answer to return the instance type of `T` when invoking `IConstruct.type` constructor function (that is probably what you want here). I also gave a bit more details to the example, hope it helps.

Comment: In the type definition of `ConstructorParameters`, what is  `? P : never`?  Is `never` a reference to a constructor that is never executed - i.e., the constructor signature of an abstract class?

Comment: @CraigHicks No, the `? : ` construct is a [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#conditional-types), [`never`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#never) the bottom type in the type system. That means nothing is assignable to it, so you can use it here as some kind of type error indication, if TS is not able to [infer](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-inference-in-conditional-types) the constructor parameters.

Answer (score 2):

The Problem has been resolved: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/31278

For me the missing `typeof` was the problem:

```
class Parent<T> {
    constructor(readonly data: T) {
    }
}
class Child<T> extends Parent<T> {
    constructor(...args: ConstructorParameters<typeof Parent<T>>) {
        super(...args);
    }
}
```